# Why ng-click is not working in my angular datatable?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I do now know, but I think jquery is conflicting with my angular datatable, but even when I take off jquery (hide and show elements), ng-click keeps not working.

Here goes as well a printscreen from my table:

[image]

My AngularJS js:

```
angular.module('BoxApp').controller("ConfiguraBkpEmail", function($scope, $http) {

var urlRestServer = "http://localhost:8080/boxmlV2";
$scope.clientes = {};
$scope.clientesSelecionados = {};

$scope.iniciar = function() {
    $http.get(urlRestServer + '/configurabkpemail').success(function(response) {
        $scope.clientes = response;

    });
};

$scope.iniciar();

$scope.selecionaClientes = function(selecao){
    $scope.clientesSelecionados = selecao;
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    if($scope.clientesSelecionados.backupEmail == 0){
//          $('#enderecoEmailBackup').hide();
//          $('#idLabel').hide();
    } else {
//          $('#enderecoEmailBackup').show();
//          $('#idLabel').show();

    }
};

/**
 * Trecho para validar o form ao submeter.
 */
$scope.submitted = false;
$scope.submitForm = function(form) {
    $scope.submitted = true;

    if (form.$valid) {
        $scope.editaEmailBkp();
    }
};  

$scope.editaEmailBkp = function() {

    var dados = {
        idCliente : idCliente.value,
        razaoSocial : razaoSocial.value,            
        backupEmail : $scope.clientesSelecionados.backupEmail,      
        enderecoEmailBackup : enderecoEmailBackup.value     
    };

    $http.post(urlRestServer + '/configurabkpemail/salvar', dados).then(function(response) {

        $scope.sucesso();
    }, function(response) {

    });

};

$scope.sucesso = function() {
    $scope.closeModal();
    $scope.iniciar();       
};

$scope.closeModal = function() {
//      $('#myModal').modal('hide');
};

$scope.opcoesBkps = [
                   {OpcaoBkpID: 0, Tipo: '0 - Sem backup de e-mail'},
                   {OpcaoBkpID: 1, Tipo: '1 - Backups inconsistentes'},
                   {OpcaoBkpID: 2, Tipo: '2 - Backup de Todos E-mails'}
];

});
```

My html:

```
            <div class="row">                       
                <table datatable="ng" id="configuraBkpEmail" class="row-border hover table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                   <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nome Empresa</th>
                            <th>CNPJ</th>
                            <th>Backup E-mail</th>
                        </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                      <tr ng-repeat="x in clientes" ng-click="selecionaClientes(x)">
                          <td><span ng-bind="x.razaoSocial" /></td>
                          <td><span ng-bind="x.cnpj" /></td>
                          <td><span ng-bind="x.strOpcaoBackupEmail" /></td>
                      </tr>
                   </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
```

My modal that should be opened:

```
      <!-- Modal INICIO-->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
             <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                 &times;
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Configuração Backup de E-mail</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="row"> 

                    <div class="col-md-12">   

                       <f<div ultimate-datatable="datatable" width="100%"></div>orm name="form" id="form_sample_2" role="form"
                           class="form-horizontal ng-pristine ng-valid" novalidate>                     

                           <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Nome:<span
                             class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span></label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                             <input type="text"
                              ng-model="clientesSelecionados.razaoSocial"
                              class="form-control" id="razaoSocial" maxlength="100"
                              name="razaoSocial" required disabled> <span
                              style="color: red"
                              ng-show="submitted && form.razaoSocial.$error.required">Campo
                              Nome Obrigatório.</span>
                            </div>
                           </div>

                           <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Backup de
                             E-mail:<span class="required" aria-required="true"> *
                            </span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                             <select size="1" name="backupEmail"
                              ng-model="clientesSelecionados.backupEmail"
                              ng-change="selecionaClientes(clientesSelecionados)"
                              class="form-control"
                              ng-options="opcoesBkp.OpcaoBkpID  as opcoesBkp.Tipo for opcoesBkp in opcoesBkps"
                              required>
                              <option value="">Selecione um Recurso.</option>
                             </select> <span style="color: red"
                              ng-show="form.backupEmail.$error.required">Selecione
                              uma opção de backup.</span>
                            </div>
                           </div>

                           <div class="form-group">
                            <label id="idLabel" class="control-label col-md-3">Endereço:<span
                             class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                             <input type="email"
                              placeholder="Endereço do Backup para encaminhamento."
                              ng-model="clientesSelecionados.enderecoEmailBackup"
                              class="form-control" id="enderecoEmailBackup"
                              maxlength="100" name="enderecoEmailBackup">

                            </div>
                           </div>

                           <div class="form-group">
                            <label id="idLabel" class="control-label col-md-3">ID:<span
                             class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span></label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                             <input type="text" ng-model="clientesSelecionados.idCliente"
                              class="form-control" id="idCliente" maxlength="100"
                              name="idCliente" disabled> <span
                              style="color: red"
                              ng-show="submitted && form.idCliente.$error.required">Campo
                              ID Obrigatório.</span>
                            </div>
                           </div>

                       </form>
                    </div>
                </div>                


               </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                     Cancelar
                    </button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submitForm(form)">
                     Salvar
                    </button>
               </div>
              </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
             </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div><!-- /.modal -->
            <!-- Modal FIM-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ng-click="$parent.selecionaClientes(x)"`.

Comment: You are absolutelly correct. Thanks !
can I know why? Please.

Comment: Because you enter to a new child-scope in ng-repeat.